# Office365ConnectorSend pipeline step does not work

Tags: jenkins, office365, webhooks, connector

I'm trying to configure Jenkinks notifications to MS Teams. I followed the instructions by setting up and configuring Jenkins app on the relevant channel and Office365 plugin in Jenkins. I get standard job status notifications if I request them.

Now I need to be able to send custom notifications from the pipeline. I was expecting that using `office365ConnectorSend` pipeline step would do just that:

```
office365ConnectorSend message:'Test message', webhoolUrl:'office365ConnectorSend message: 'Manual test', webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/.../JenkinsCI/...'
```

When the pipeline runs, everything is reported as working correctly and the job completes successfully, yet the message never appears in teams.

How can post a message?

Answer (score 4):

> office365ConnectorSend message:'Test message', webhoolUrl:'office365ConnectorSend message: 'Manual test', webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/.../JenkinsCI/...'

Did you check the spelling? it should be webhookUrl not webhoolUrl and only once.
I use something like this in the post pipeline action step, where MSTEAMS_HOOK is defined as an environment variable within the environment {} pipeline directive to the Teams URL.

```
  success {
    office365ConnectorSend (
    status: "Pipeline Status",
    webhookUrl: "${MSTEAMS_HOOK}",
    color: '00ff00',
    message: "Test Successful: ${JOB_NAME} - ${BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}<br>Pipeline duration: ${currentBuild.durationString}"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the single quote to double in the webhookUrl.

webhookUrl:"$msteams_url"

Answer (score 0):

Except for the spell error, the script you have been trying works fine. The problem might be with your network restriction. The HTTP request triggered by jenkins might have been blocked. Try pasting the webhook URL in the browser of the system you are using and check the response. If the response says something other than *'Invalid webhook request - GET not supported'*. There is a possibility the request has been a failure.

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
            office365ConnectorSend message: 'Manual test', webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/*'
         }
      }
   }
}
```